# Warnings inmatrix multiplication in vhdl

Tags: matrix, vhdl, multiplication

So, I started writing the code for a simple 4x4 matrix multiplication. The code is very crude at this point, something I will try to change by the end, but I just wanted to see if it works. 
It uses direct assignment to the 2-bit elements of the matrices from the 8-bit inputs. Similarly, the 4 outputs are created by concatenating the 4 elements of each row of the resulting matrix. Below you can see the code.

The problem I have is that after I run the code, I get about 100 warnings of the type 
"There is an 'U'|'X'|'W'|'Z'|'-' in an arithmetic operand, the result will be 'X'(es)."
What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the initialization of the variables A, B, temp, or something else?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY matrix_mul IS
    PORT( 
    a1: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    a2: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    a3: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    a4: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    b1: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    b2: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    b3: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    b4: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    x1: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    x2: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    x3: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    x4: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END matrix_mul;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF matrix_mul IS

TYPE array_2b_1x4 IS ARRAY (3 DOWNTO 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE matrix_2b_4x4 IS ARRAY (3 DOWNTO 0) of array_2b_1x4;
TYPE array_4b_1x4 IS ARRAY (3 DOWNTO 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE matrix_4b_4x4 IS ARRAY (3 DOWNTO 0) of array_4b_1x4;


BEGIN
    PROCESS (a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4)
    VARIABLE A : matrix_2b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    VARIABLE B : matrix_2b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    VARIABLE temp : matrix_4b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));

    BEGIN
        A(0)(0) := a1(7 DOWNTO 6);
        A(0)(1) := a1(5 DOWNTO 4);
        A(0)(2) := a1(3 DOWNTO 2);
        A(0)(3) := a1(1 DOWNTO 0);
        A(1)(0) := a2(7 DOWNTO 6);
        A(1)(1) := a2(5 DOWNTO 4);
        A(1)(2) := a2(3 DOWNTO 2);
        A(1)(3) := a2(1 DOWNTO 0);
        A(2)(0) := a3(7 DOWNTO 6);
        A(2)(1) := a3(5 DOWNTO 4);
        A(2)(2) := a3(3 DOWNTO 2);
        A(2)(3) := a3(1 DOWNTO 0);
        A(3)(0) := a4(7 DOWNTO 6);
        A(3)(1) := a4(5 DOWNTO 4);
        A(3)(2) := a4(3 DOWNTO 2);
        A(3)(3) := a4(1 DOWNTO 0);
        B(0)(0) := b1(7 DOWNTO 6);
        B(0)(1) := b1(5 DOWNTO 4);
        B(0)(2) := b1(3 DOWNTO 2);
        B(0)(3) := b1(1 DOWNTO 0);
        B(1)(0) := b2(7 DOWNTO 6);
        B(1)(1) := b2(5 DOWNTO 4);
        B(1)(2) := b2(3 DOWNTO 2);
        B(1)(3) := b2(1 DOWNTO 0);
        B(2)(0) := b3(7 DOWNTO 6);
        B(2)(1) := b3(5 DOWNTO 4);
        B(2)(2) := b3(3 DOWNTO 2);
        B(2)(3) := b3(1 DOWNTO 0);
        B(3)(0) := b4(7 DOWNTO 6);
        B(3)(1) := b4(5 DOWNTO 4);
        B(3)(2) := b4(3 DOWNTO 2);
        B(3)(3) := b4(1 DOWNTO 0);


        FOR i IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
            FOR j IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
                FOR k IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
                    temp(i)(j) := temp(i)(j) + ( A(i)(k) * B(k)(j) );
                END LOOP;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;

        x1 <= temp(0)(0) & temp(0)(1) & temp(0)(2) & temp(0)(3);
        x2 <= temp(1)(0) & temp(1)(1) & temp(1)(2) & temp(1)(3);
        x3 <= temp(2)(0) & temp(2)(1) & temp(2)(2) & temp(2)(3);
        x4 <= temp(3)(0) & temp(3)(1) & temp(3)(2) & temp(3)(3);

    END PROCESS;
END arch;
```

Comment: As the whole thing appears to be unclocked, I suggest these messages may be glitches as valid values propagate through to the outputs. If they stop after a while (less than a clock period!) and you see valid outputs, you're good.

Comment: I get only XXX.. in the outputs so I'm not sure what is wrong. Not sure what you mean with the "after a while", but I post an image which shows what I see after running it for a while

Comment: http://i1140.photobucket.com/albums/n575/artdevil27/2016-01-15_231643_zps8dkr445z.png

Comment: I can see it but not add it to the question. As you have the original image I suggest you do. Anyway, the next move should be to add the internal signals to the Wave window, see which ones are correct, which aren't - that'll help show what's wrong.

Comment: Your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without a method of reproducing the error (it does reproduce).  The problem is temp is used as an accumulator driven by input events, which includes the initial value events. Register temp (and potentially reset it). This would work for IEEE package numeric_bit_unsigned and bit_vector because the default value is '0's.

Comment: I tried something else, by turning the matrix to integer from std_logic_vector and it works without any issues, other than a few warnings, which I will probably ignore since they don't affect the result. Now I just have to turn the result to std_logic_vector and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these initialization at the variable declarations within the process

```
VARIABLE A : matrix_2b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
VARIABLE B : matrix_2b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
VARIABLE temp : matrix_4b_4x4 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
```

take place **only once** when the process ia executed the **first** time.

You haven't posted your testbench, but I suspect `a` and `b` are not initialized at the declarations there. Thus, they are all `'U'` when the process is executed the first time. Thus, `temp` is assigned some / all `'X'`es. After you assigned some valid values to `a` and `b` within the testbench, the process is executed again, but `temp` is still assigned the value from the last run at the beginning and contains `'X'`es and will keep them in the addition.

This, is not what you want in a your matrix multiplication. You have described a combinational process, so that, you have to initialize all variables in the process for **every** run. This way, it does not depend on the previous run, so that, the accumulation starts every from `temp` = zero. You have already a proper assignment of `A` and `B` in the process, but `temp` is missing. Just init it before the `for` loops:

```
...
temp := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
FOR i IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
...
```

After making this change, you can remove the variable initialization at the variable declaration.